# element + element cant access :before pseudo

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I have a situation where i have two elements which are same level in DOM (neighbours). When i hover element which is before in DOM i want the element below it to be shown. Also i want access child of the element Im showing and show its `:before` pseudo element.

SCSS

```
&__wrapper {
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;

        &:hover {

            + .filter-time__shortcuts {
                opacity: 1;
                visibility: visible;
                pointer-events: auto;
                transform: scale(1) translateY(0);

                .filter-time__shortcuts-list {
                    transform: scale(0.5);

                    &:before {
                        display: block;
                    }

                }

            }

        }
```

Everything works except displaying of `:before` pseudo element. For some reason it cant access it but it can access `.filter-time__shortcuts-list`.
When i move the `:hover` to parent of both elements, where both are children and there is no need for `+` selector it works. Whats going on?

Compiled CSS

```
.filter-time__wrapper:hover + .filter-time__shortcuts .filter-time__shortcuts-list:before {
        display: block; }
```

edit: https://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/vWExqN

Comment: Please add a full test case, e.g. include HTML and add a Code Snippet.

Comment: We can't tell if your CSS selector is right or wrong unless we can see your HTML.

Comment: Have you got a `content` style on the :before element? This is required even if it's blank.

Comment: @delinear yes, as i said this is working when i put hover on parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answer is that css really was accessing the `:before` element. The thing was when i wanted to access the dropdown with mouse I'm not really hovering the trigger anymore. When i put the hover on the parent I'm hovering the trigger (the whole parent) all the time.